# Чи тотожні значення дістати і здобути

Tags: вибір-слова, синоніми

В [мовознавчій консультації](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/112337/23-Horodenska.pdf?sequence=1) з приводу розрізнення дієслів *дістати* і *здобути* маємо чітке розмежування:

> Дієслово ***діставати*** закріпилося в ужитку із значеннями (СУМ, ІІ, 308):
>
> 1. *брати, витягувати що-небудь звідкись*;
> 2. *дотягуючись, досягаючи, доторкатися до чого-небудь*;
> 3. *здобувати, відшукувати що-небудь, долаючи труднощі*.
>
> Слово ***здобувати*** у всіх випадках вживання (СУМ, ІІІ,
>   543) містить сему *отримати результат, докладаючи певних
>   зусиль* і може мати значення *діставати, розшукувати знаходити кого, що-небудь*. В контексті слово здобувати часто функціонує зі значенням *наполегливо досягати чого-небудь у впертій боротьбі, навчанні*.

Російсько-український словник сталих виразів обидва слова наводить як варіанти перекладу „снискать благодарность“:

> • Снискать, приобрести чью благосклонность (добиться благосклонности, заслужить благосклонность) – запобігти (недокон. запобігати) ласки (милості) чиєї (в кого); *здобути (недокон. здобувати) ласку чию (в кого)*; добутися (добуватися) ласки чиєї (в кого); добутися (добуватися) до ласки кому; підійти (підходити) під чию ласку; *дістати (діставати) ласки в кого*.

Чи можна сказати, що *діставати* має більш широке значення і може вживатися замість *здобувати*, але не навпаки?

Comment: Наведена цитата прямо відповідає на ваше запитання (відповідь «так»). У чому полягає запитання? Чи ви шукаєте підтвердження/спростування, ґрунтоване на більшій кількості джерел?

Comment: @bytebuster, на початку запитання є посилання на мовознавчу консультацію з категоричною відповіддю. Але словник сталих виразів дає можливість подвійного використання слова діставати. Питання в тому, на кого спиратися.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Словник синонімів Полюги***

> **[ДІСТАВАТИ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/31/53396/27948.html)**  що *(ставати власником чогось)* здобувати, розм.:
>   прихоплювати, прихвачувати; док.: *(брати очікуване)* одержати,
>   отримати, *(здобути щось у праці, навчанні, як наслідок — нагорода)*
>   заробити, здобути, заслужити, уроч. удостоїтися.
>
> **[ЗДОБУВАТИ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/31/53399/28126.html)**  *(досягати чогось великими зусиллями)* виборювати,
>   осягати, завойовувати.

***Словник синонімів Караванського***

> **[ДІСТАВАТИ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53396/264016.html)**  *(звідки)* брати, витягати: *(рукою)* досягати; *(дані*)
>   здобувати, відшукувати; *(листи)* одержувати, отримувати: *(насолоду)*
>   мати; *(грипу)* підхоплювати, захворювати на, заражатися чим; *(енергію)*
>   видобувати, виробляти; ЖМ. вистачати, ставати; док. ДІСТАТИ, *(у пику)*
>   зловити, спіймати.
>
> **[ЗДОБУВАТИ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53399/265559.html)**  роздобувати; *(з бою)* брати; *(працею)* заробляти,
>   дороблятися; *(право)* завойовувати; *(щастя)* засягати, досягати; *(славу)*
>   заживати чого, убиватися в що; *(освіту)* осягати; *(серце)* знаходити
>   дорогу до чого; *(з кишені)* виймати, витягати; *(вогонь)* добувати;
>   *(копалини)* видобувати.

Можна зробити висновок, що *дістати* має більш широке значення і можемо вживати замість *здобувати*, але не навпаки.